# Hydrogen peroxide and glycerol combination

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, redox, aqueous-solution, organic-oxidation, decomposition

Is the mixing of store-grade hydrogen peroxide 3% and glycerol in the ratio of 1:2 (V/V) at room temperature affecting the decomposition rate of hydrogen peroxide?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to ruin both reagents, then you can go ahead and mix them. Hydrogen peroxide oxidizes glycerol to various reagents. A possible reaction pathway can be depicted as follows (Ref.1):

[image: Oxidation of Glycerol]

This reaction is catalyzed by transition metals and other substances (Ref.1-3).

**References:**

1. G. Wu, X. Wang, T. Jiang, Q. Lin, “Selective Oxidation of Glycerol with 3% $\ce{H2O2}$ Catalyzed by LDH-Hosted Cr(III) Complex,” *Catalysts* **2015**, *5(4)*, 2039– 2051 (https://doi.org/10.3390/catal5042039).
2. D. Mandelli, W. A. Carvalho, L. S. Shul'pina, A. M. Kirillov,  M. V. Kirillova, A. J. L. Pombeiro,  G. B. Shul'pin, “Chapter 19: Oxidation of Glycerol with Hydrogen Peroxide Catalyzed by Metal Complexes,” In *Advances in Organometallic Chemistry and Catalysis: The Silver/Gold Jubilee International Conference on Organometallic Chemistry Celebratory Book*; A. J. L. Pombeiro, Ed.;  John Wiley & Sons, Inc.: New York, NY, 2014, pp. 247– 257 (https://doi.org/10.1002/9781118742952.ch19).
3. P. McMorn, G. Roberts, G. J. Hutchings, “Oxidation of glycerol with hydrogen peroxide using silicalite and aluminophosphate catalysts,” *Catalysis Letters* **1999**, *63(3-4)*, 193– 197 (https://doi.org/10.1023/A:101907312).

Comment: Hmm, interesting, I would not think oxidation stops at formic and oxalic acid.

Comment: @Poutnik: I was surprized too. But this is s peer-reviewed papar so put my trust on the work. :-)